# How to pass multivalues parameters in MDX calculated members?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

I'm actually working on a SSAS Cube using SQL Server Reporting Services.
In order to filter a field, I need to use a calculated member which specifically use a parameter.

Here is my calculated member:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Comparable Stock Room] AS Iif (
    [Stock room].[Stock room code].currentMember IS (Iif (STRTOMEMBER(@StockRoomCode).Count = 1, STRTOMEMBER(@StockRoomCode), xxx)),
    0,
    [Measures].[Retail sales amount invoiced including tax] 
)
```

This works well if @StockRoomCode only have one value. But I don't know how to make it works when the parameter has multiple values. How to replace the 'xxx' ?
Can you help me or tell me how to do it a better way, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could create a calculated member aggregating the members you want to report on and define the measure in tems of the calculated member, something like:

```
with member [Stock Room].[Stock room code].[foo] as
aggregate (strtoset (@StockRoomCode)),

member [Measures].[Comparable Stock Room] as
([Stock Room].[Stock room code].[foo],
 [Measures].[Retail sales amount including tax])
```

(Note: not tested, just off the top of my head). Or,

```
with set [foo] as strtoset (@StockRoomCode),

member [Measures].[Comparable Stock Room] as
       sum ([foo], [Measures].[Retail sales amount including tax])

select [Measures].[Comparable Stock Room] on columns,
       (Slicing dimension such as time) on rows
  from [cube]
 where [other slice]
```

Note, with either, get your set expression right and test that first.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I tried what you said and it didn't work... Even with one value for @StockRoomCode, it keep saying NULL for the column Comparable Stock Room.

Comment: Try building it up by parts.  Get the set correct (strtoset (@StockRoomCode) first.

Comment: Building it up by parts was the first thing I tried when it started to piss me off... @StockRoomCode keep saying 'NULL' everytime I use it. I can't find a way to display the value into a column... that's crazy cause' when I use it in the condition (Iif...), it was able to retrieve the right value...